# Validating using javascript (beginner level)

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to validate a date input from a form using 'indexOf' and I tried this but doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix it please? The && bit is showing an error. Clearly that isn't how I am supposed to write it. Minor fix I believe.

Comment: You can edit your own question...

Comment: Can you post the html source?

Comment: offtopic: @ash_raj2209, prefer to initialize your variable with `var`: `var yes = ...`, otherwise your variable will be created in the global scope instead of in the function scope, and it can lead to unexpected results if you use it outside the function.

Comment: I added the html @SuperStormer

Comment: Ah yes thank you @saulotoledo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also important thing to notice in your code.

```js
yes = (document.wedding.date.value.indexOf("/") == 2 && 5)
```

The use of logical `&&` AND operator is wrong in here. This operator **always** separates two different logical expression. Your second expression is `5` which converts to always be true. So what your expression means in words is `if first index of slash is 2(true/false) AND 5(true)` but it should be `if first index of slash is 2 AND if second index of slash is 5`.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. However how can I fix this? Should I put the index of 5 in a different variable?

Comment: `yes = (document.wedding.date.value.indexOf("/") == 2 && document.wedding.date.value.indexOf("/", 2) == 5)`

Answer (score 0):

instead of indexOf you could use a regular expression like so :

```js
function validate(){
        yes = (document.wedding.date.value.match(/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/)

            if(!yes) 
            alert("Incorrect Date Format");
    }
```

This regular expressions matches dates of the form XX/XX/YYYY where XX can be 1 or 2 digits long and YYYY is always 4 digits long.